# AdView.LoadAd keeps throwing an error in Xamarin app created using Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, admob

I am having an error within AdMobViewRenderer class implemented in Android native while trying to integrate Google AdMob into my Xamarin app created in Visual Studio 2022.

The  adView.LoadAd line keeps throwing the error [The method java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass() was expected to be of type interface but instead was found to be of type virtual ( declaration of com.google.android.gms.dynamic.Object appears in dataapp/myapppackagename-1/base.apk]

private AdView CreateAdView(int adWidth)
{
try
{
AdView adView = new AdView(Context);
adView.AdUnitId = Element.AdUnitId;
if (Element.AdType == "MediumRectangle")
{
adView.AdSize = AdSize.MediumRectangle;
}
else
{
adView.AdSize = AdSize.GetPortraitInlineAdaptiveBannerAdSize(Context, adWidth);
}

```
            adView.LayoutParameters = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MatchParent, LayoutParams.MatchParent);
            //var adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
            
            //THIS LINE THROWS THE ERRROR                
            adView.LoadAd(new AdRequest
                            .Builder()
                            .Build());
            return adView;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            CommonFunction.DisplayAlert("AdMobRenderer CreateAdView Failed= ", ex.Message, "OK", MainActivity.Instance);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like [this issue](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/654). Until someone fixes it, try a version of nuget earlier than the ones mentioned in that issue.

Comment: thank you. I will try using older version

Comment: the error goes away and Test Ad starts showing up after I added Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads.Lite version 120.3.0.3